# Why create method in rails not store from Front-End and yes with Postman

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save

i have an error when create data

I Try insert data with POSTMAN

[image]

And receiving data is correctly

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"cat_branch_office_id"=>"1", "cat_product_id"=>"1", "cat_unit_id"=>"1", "cat_location_id"=>"1", "cat_tag_id"=>"1", "codigo"=>"XOXO", "nombre"=>"Omeprazol POSTMAN", "nombre_farmacia"=>"Acido absorbico", "descripcion"=>"Aderogyl es un auxiliar en la prevención y tratamiento del resfriado comun, generalmente conocido como gripe. Refuerzas las defensas, fortaleciendo el sistema imunologico", "cantidad"=>"50", "max"=>"500", "min"=>"10", "precio_costo"=>"0", "precio_venta"=>"0", "foto"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fa820c1caf8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210226-1-16imkz6.png>, @original_filename="omeprazol.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foto\"; filename=\"omeprazol.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">} permitted: true>
```

The log that rails show me when insert correctly, is this:

```
TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  CatBranchOffice Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "cat_branch_offices".* FROM "cat_branch_offices" WHERE "cat_branch_offices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  CatProduct Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "cat_products".* FROM "cat_products" WHERE "cat_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  CatUnit Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "cat_units".* FROM "cat_units" WHERE "cat_units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  CatLocation Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "cat_locations".* FROM "cat_locations" WHERE "cat_locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  CatTag Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "cat_tags".* FROM "cat_tags" WHERE "cat_tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  Product Create (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "products" ("cat_branch_office_id", "cat_product_id", "cat_unit_id", "cat_location_id", "cat_tag_id", "codigo", "nombre", "nombre_farmacia", "descripcion", "cantidad", "max", "min", "precio_costo", "precio_venta", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16) RETURNING "id"  [["cat_branch_office_id", 1], ["cat_product_id", 1], ["cat_unit_id", 1], ["cat_location_id", 1], ["cat_tag_id", 1], ["codigo", "XOXO"], ["nombre", "Omeprazol POSTMAN"], ["nombre_farmacia", "Acido absorbico"], ["descripcion", "Aderogyl es un auxiliar en la prevención y tratamiento del resfriado comun, generalmente conocido como gripe. Refuerzas las defensas, fortaleciendo el sistema imunologico"], ["cantidad", 50], ["max", 500], ["min", 10], ["precio_costo", 0.0], ["precio_venta", 0.0], ["created_at", "2021-02-26 15:40:07.190547"], ["updated_at", "2021-02-26 15:40:07.190547"]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Load (1.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" INNER JOIN "active_storage_attachments" ON "active_storage_blobs"."id" = "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 6], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "foto"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 6], ["record_type", "Product"], ["name", "foto"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Blob Create (1.1ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_blobs" ("key", "filename", "content_type", "metadata", "service_name", "byte_size", "checksum", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id"  [["key", "4ntznfxxcvidnsl0fd11s3c6rjss"], ["filename", "omeprazol.png"], ["content_type", "image/png"], ["metadata", "{\"identified\":true}"], ["service_name", "local"], ["byte_size", 402174], ["checksum", "BaHefYB9yvAzg4BDxHzHTQ=="], ["created_at", "2021-02-26 15:40:07.318132"]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Create (0.8ms)  INSERT INTO "active_storage_attachments" ("name", "record_type", "record_id", "blob_id", "created_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "foto"], ["record_type", "Product"], ["record_id", 6], ["blob_id", 20], ["created_at", "2021-02-26 15:40:07.324929"]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  Product Update (1.1ms)  UPDATE "products" SET "updated_at" = $1 WHERE "products"."id" = $2  [["updated_at", "2021-02-26 15:40:07.329089"], ["id", 6]]
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (3.5ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ (pry):14:in `create'
  Disk Storage (40.7ms) Uploaded file to key: 4ntznfxxcvidnsl0fd11s3c6rjss (checksum: BaHefYB9yvAzg4BDxHzHTQ==)
[ActiveJob] Enqueued ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6) to Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fa81c2e2838 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://code/ActiveStorage::Blob/20>>
=> true
[2] pry(#<Api::V1::ProductsController>)>   ActiveStorage::Blob Load (2.1ms)  SELECT "active_storage_blobs".* FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6] Performing ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6) from Async(default) enqueued at 2021-02-26T15:40:07Z with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00007fa81c265a68 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://code/ActiveStorage::Blob/20>>
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6]   Disk Storage (6.5ms) Downloaded file from key: 4ntznfxxcvidnsl0fd11s3c6rjss
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6]   TRANSACTION (1.2ms)  BEGIN
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6]   ActiveStorage::Blob Update (4.4ms)  UPDATE "active_storage_blobs" SET "metadata" = $1 WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $2  [["metadata", "{\"identified\":true,\"width\":607,\"height\":391,\"analyzed\":true}"], ["id", 20]]
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6]   TRANSACTION (3.9ms)  COMMIT
[ActiveJob] [ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob] [769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6] Performed ActiveStorage::AnalyzeJob (Job ID: 769238d2-71f8-49c0-914e-6e5c8da909a6) from Async(default) in 410.18ms
```

When try store data with Front-End APP, i receiving this data in my controller method create

```
#<ActionController::Parameters {"cat_branch_office_id"=>"1", "cat_product_id"=>"3", "cat_unit_id"=>"3", "cat_location_id"=>"1", "cat_tag_id"=>"1", "codigo"=>"1021", "nombre"=>"Omeprazol", "nombre_farmacia"=>"dfasf", "descripcion"=>"El omeprazol se utiliza en el tratamiento de la dispepsia, úlcera péptica, enfermedades por reflujo gastroesofágico y el síndrome de Zollinger-Ellison", "cantidad"=>"10", "max"=>"100", "min"=>"30", "precio_costo"=>"null", "precio_venta"=>"58.5", "foto"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007fa81c32cfc8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20210226-1-xvxroj.png>, @original_filename="omeprazol.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"foto\"; filename=\"omeprazol.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">} permitted: true>
```

The data is receiving correctly, but when try store, i get this in my log

```
 TRANSACTION (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ (pry):23:in `create'
  CatBranchOffice Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "cat_branch_offices".* FROM "cat_branch_offices" WHERE "cat_branch_offices"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):23:in `create'
  CatProduct Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "cat_products".* FROM "cat_products" WHERE "cat_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):23:in `create'
  CatUnit Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "cat_units".* FROM "cat_units" WHERE "cat_units"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):23:in `create'
  CatLocation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "cat_locations".* FROM "cat_locations" WHERE "cat_locations"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):23:in `create'
  CatTag Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "cat_tags".* FROM "cat_tags" WHERE "cat_tags"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ (pry):23:in `create'
  TRANSACTION (0.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  ↳ (pry):23:in `create'
=> false
```

I don't know what happends u.u

This error only get in create method, when update, my data is store correctly from POSTMAN or Front-end app

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
@product.save!
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Precio costo is not a number
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/activerecord-6.1.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:80:in `raise_validation_error'
```

Now i can see where is my problem, modify my validation in model and my problem was solve.

Thanks to all